# How to ask user permission in private browser session?

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api

I noticed a very frustrating situation on `Google OAuth2` where the email passed is different against the account actually connected to the system. Let me explain better, I wrote this method that ask user permission for access my app to user private Google Calendars:

```
public static CalendarService OAuth(string userName)
{
    string[] scopes = new string[]
    {
         CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
         CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly
    };

    try
    {
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
        {
             ClientId = "client id Google Developer Console",
             ClientSecret = "Secret key Google Developer Console"
        },
        scopes,
        userName,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("Stored.Token")).Result;

        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
              HttpClientInitializer = credential,
              ApplicationName = "Application name"
        });
      return service;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
          return null;
     }
 }
```

Now someone already have understood the situation but I want to explain why this procedure is bad for me. Suppose that I want create an application that as the fist screen allow the user to insert personal email, this email should be used by the method `OAuth` as the parameter `userName` for ask user permission on Google Browser window.

Until here no problem, the user has entered the email and the application open Google Chrome browser for ask to him the permission to access to private calendars.
But, what's happean if the Google account connected actually in the `Chrome` browser is different against the email passed?

What's happean if the user that use the application grant the access with a different account connected and him doesn't noticed this?

The application will use a different account for upload the data and the user can thought that stay upload data on personal calendar. Someone have work around this situation, maybe opening Chrome, after `UserCredential` code block in a private browser, and if yes, in this case the token will stored in the folder specificed: `AppData\Roaming\Stored.Token`?

**Practice example:**

**1**. User type private email in my app: `foo@gmail.com`

**2**. App launch Chrome session and ask User permission, account acctually connected `bar@gmail.com`

**3**. User doesn't noticed this situation and grant my app to access to `bar@gmail.com`

**4**. My app will use `bar@gmail.com` for upload event, but the user thinks that the app stay using `foo@gmail.com`

**5**. The chaos.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of different account can be prevented by performing the OAuth flow and updating private browser session with the granted token and scopes.

Reading through the [Basics of Authentication](https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/), we have:

**1. Registering your app**

Every registered OAuth application is assigned a unique Client ID and Client Secret which should never be shared. When you register your application, you can fill out every piece of information except the **Authorization callback URL**, also considered as the most important piece of setting up your application. It's the callback URL where a user will be redirected after successful authentication.

**2. Accepting user authorization**

Your client ID and client secret keys come from your application's configuration page which was recommended to be stored as environment variables as shown in the sample code.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Well, hello there!
    </p>
    <p>
      We're going to now talk to the GitHub API. Ready?
      <a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=<%= client_id %>">Click here</a> to begin!</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      If that link doesn't work, remember to provide your own <a href="/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow">Client ID</a>!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that the URL uses the scope query parameter to define the scopes requested by the application. For the sample code, we requested `user:email` scope for reading email addresses. After you click on the link you should be taken to Authorization page. and then will be redirected to a route specified in `Callback URL`. You will be provided with a temporary code value to be added in a POST HTTP request in exchange for an `access_token` then you'll be able to make authenticated requests as the logged user.

```
# fetch user information
auth_result = JSON.parse(RestClient.get('https://api.github.com/user',
                                        {:params => {:access_token => access_token}}))

# if the user authorized it, fetch private emails
if has_user_email_scope
  auth_result['private_emails'] =
    JSON.parse(RestClient.get('https://api.github.com/user/emails',
                              {:params => {:access_token => access_token}}))
end

erb :basic, :locals => auth_result
```

And lastly,

**3. Implementing "persistent" authentication**

As recommended:

> Since we're persisting scopes within the session, we'll need to handle cases when the user updates the scopes after we checked them, or revokes the token. To do that, we'll use a rescue block and check that the first API call succeeded, which verifies that the token is still valid. After that, we'll check the X-OAuth-Scopes response header to verify that the user hasn't revoked the user:email scope.

Implementing the code shown in developer github,  we now have the `authenticated` method which checks if the user is already authenticated. If not, the `authenticate` method is called, which performs the OAuth flow and updates the session with the granted token and scopes.

Comment: How your answer solve the problem? I think this can't be fixed by user 'cause it's Google that should change the .NET DLL so implement an account selection before asking permission. I've done some research and I didn't found any solution. The workaround that proposed IlDrugo to open a private session of the browser may be a solution, but you must consider the following: 1. A private session in some way allows you to obtain an access token? 2. How can you tell the API to open a private session behind code? 3. Somehow is this in compliance with the terms of Google's license?